# postgresql: how to know when a function was modified

Tags: postgresql

Scenario: 
Someone creates a function named "foo" in a PostgreSQL database.
Next, someone modifies the inner workings of function "foo".

Question:
Does PostgreSQL offer a means to know who modified function "foo" and when "foo" was modified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can use [EVENT TRIGGERS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html) and you can create them on any of [these DDL events listed here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abort_any_command()
  RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE EXCEPTION '[%] user % attempt command % which disabled',
    current_timestamp,
    current_user,
    tg_tag;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER abort_ddl ON ddl_command_start
  WHEN TAG IN ('DROP FUNCTION', 'CREATE FUNCTION')
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE abort_any_command();
```

You can create the `EVENT TRIGGER` on `ddl_command_end` if you want an event to trigger ONLY after the operation has completed successfully. After you create an `EVENT TRIGGER`, you can try to drop the function and you'll see.

```
DROP FUNCTION abort_any_command();
ERROR:  [2017-01-09 20:27:33.843529-06] user ecarroll attempt command DROP FUNCTION which disabled
```

If you just want it in the logs, rather than to raise the exception then use [a different level than `RAISE EXCEPTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html). You should also easily be able to make this `INSERT` into a table if you'd like.